# Hive multiple subqueries and group by

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb, emr, hiveql

I'm switching statistics from MySQL to Amazon DynamoDB and Elastic MapReduce.

I have query bellow that works with MySQL and I have the same table on hive and need the same results as on MySQL (product views for last_week, last_month and last_year).

```
SELECT product_id,
SELECT COUNT(product_id) from dev_product_views_hive as P2 where P2.product_id=P.product_id and created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) as weekly,
SELECT count(product_id) from dev_product_views_hive as P3 where P3.product_id=P.product_id and created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as monthly,
SELECT count(product_id) from dev_product_views_hive as P4 where P4.product_id=P.product_id and created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) as yearly
from dev_product_views_hive as P group by product_id;
```

I figured out how to get results for example for last month with hive:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) as views from dev_product_views_hive WHERE created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), 31)," ","00:00:00")) GROUP BY product_id;
```

but i need grouped results like I get with MySql:

```
product_id views_last_week views_last_month views_last_year
2                 564             2460         29967
4                 980             3986         54982
```

Is it possible to do this with hive?

Thank you in advance,

Amer

Comment: Yes, always get parse error, i don't know how to write this MySQL subqueries correctly in hiveql. Hiveql doesn't same syntax like MySQL.

Comment: hive ql supports subqueries only in from clause

Comment: I know that, is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `case when`  and `sum()` or `count()`

eg.

```
select product_id, 
sum(case when created >= concat(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 7)," 00:00:00") then 1 else 0 end)  as weekly,
sum(case when created >= concat(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 31)," 00:00:00") then 1 else 0 end) as monthly,
sum(case when created >= concat(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 365)," 00:00:00") then 1 else 0 end) as yearly
from dev_product_views_hive 
group by product_id;
```

`concat(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), days)," 00:00:00")` will return the formatted string of days past current time.

and

`case when` will reterun 1 when created `>=` the days what you expected

You can also do it with hive built-in function `count()` which only counts those rows return non-NULL

```
count(case when created >= concat(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 7)," 00:00:00") then 1 end)  as weekly
```